# have some wondering about matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xx1 = np.random.randint(1,7,100)
xx2 = np.random.randint(1,7,100)
dice = xx1 + xx2
plt.hist(dice,normed = True)
plt.show()
```

1. What does normed = True do?
2. While doing a ploting, must we open with `plt.figure()` first?
3. To be able to draw a graph by using matplotlib, should it has to be a np array or it can be work with the regular list? eg. `range(100)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See the docs here: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist
2. You don't always have to call `plt.figure()`. You don't need to call it to plot a single figure, as demonstrated by your example code. However for multiple figures (as opposed to subplots) you will need to make use of it.
3. Yes it will work with regular lists.

Comment: Oops, you beat me to it. I'll delete mine.